# While condition should check whether the sum of two variables is below a threshold or not

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model in which my agents should drive to work. However, their reach is limited that's why I want to use a WHILE function to check whether the distance driven *to* the destination (*distance-to-work*) plus the distance driven *at* the destination (e.g. using their own car for a delivery service = *distance-to-work*) is below a certain threshold (here, 130 km). The idea is that the agents can drive to and return from work if they only drive up to 130 km, that is, the sum of *distance-to-work* and *distance-at-work* should be less than 130. Otherwise, they would run out of gasoline.

The distances are drawn according to a probability distribution. The probability for each variable is called chance_distance_to_work and chance_distance_from_work, respectively. E.g. with a probability of 3% they drive 2km to work, with a probability of 8%, they drive 4km to work, etc. The same goes for the distance driven at work. I intend to derive the distances via a nested ifelse-statement.

I would like to repeat the "drawing" of my chance_distance_to/at_work variable until the sum of both variables (distance-to/at-work) is 130 or less, which allows them to come back to their home place.

```
turtle-own [
distance-to-work
distance-at-work
]

to setup-driving-pattern

ask full-time-employees [

; the loop should continue until the sum of both, distance-to-work 
; and distance-at-work is 130 or less
while [distance-to-work + distance-at-work >= 131] [

; I created two variables for the chance of each variable,
; in order to assign a certain number (km). This variable 
; should draw a random number between 0 and 99. According 
; to this number (or probability) the respective 
, distance-to-work or distance-at-work is drawn.

let chance_distance_at_work random 100
let chance_distance_to_work random 100

; here is a nested ifelse statement which continues until 100%, 
; but this is just an example
ifelse chance_distance_to_work < 3 [set distance-to-work 2 ] [
ifelse chance_distance_to_work < 8 [set distance-to-work 4 ] ... ]

ifelse chance_distance_at_work < 4  [set distance-at-work 1 ] [
ifelse chance_distance_at_work < 12 [set distance-at-work 2 ] ... ]
 ]
]

end
```

I guess something is wrong with the addition within the WHILE function. Because without the while function each turtle (here, full-time-employee) gets his own variable for distance-to-work and distance-at-work. Moreover, if the condition or the reporter does not state [distance-to-work + distance-at-work **>=** 131], but [distance-to-work + distance-at-work **<** 131] instead, it works. So the WHILE function returns the distance-to-work and distance-at-work if the sum is bigger than 130. But if I just switch the sign, it does not work anymore and the assigned values for both variables are always 0, so the default value.

I can set up both variables independently, i.e. I can obtain a value for each variable. However, if I now want to combine both variables and check whether their sum is below a certain threshold (e.g. 130), then both variables are always determined as 0.

Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the problem, but my reply is too long for a "comment" so I will put it here as "an answer".

First, there is no closing bracket for this open one: "ask full-time-employees [ " so I will assume you wanted one more "]" at the very end.

But, you do not have the correct syntax for the "while" statement -- it must have brackets around both the test and the commands to run if the test passes.  That is, it always must look like this:

while [   ] [   ]

You only have this:
 while [ ]

So the editor will give you an error: "While expected two inputs, a TRUE/FALSE block and a command block."

Again, I assume you meant for the rest of the code to be inside the WHILE loop.

Since I don't see a "let" statement for them, I tried to assume that distance-to-work and distance-at-work are global variables.  ( Please post all your code next time so we do not need to guess! )   But, if they are meant to be global variables, your code will fail, because they will be initialized to zero, so the WHILE test will always fail.

Anyway, it makes no sense to me that you are testing whether the sum of these is greater than 130 and if it is, then **keep driving**.   I am going to assume you want to **STOP** driving when the total distance driven is over 130 km.

The the WHILE test will be TRUE for the first employee, but these numbers will increase until finally the WHILE test will fail, and the employee will stop driving.  But nothing you have written will RESET these variables to zero, so the WHILE test will fail for every other driver.   Not good.

So, these need to be local variables, not global variables, and they need to be declared ( by a "let" statement ) and initialized to zero inside the "ask full-time-employees [ ]
block and near the start of that block.

Next, I do not understand what you are trying to do, where you have tests like this:

```
ifelse chance_distance_to_work < 3 [set distance-to-work 2 ] [ ...]
```

WHY would you do such a thing?  I would think that what you want to do is simply add the new chance_distance_to_work to the old running total "distance-to-work", then add the new chance_distance_at_work to the old running total "distance-at-work", and then end the block.    Then you are ending the block with (distance-at-work  + distance-at-work) equal to the total distance driven so far, and you can test that in the next pass of the WHILE loop.  Right?

I will assume that is correct, and here is the code with those changes made in it. This code will run. I put in many "print" statements to show what it is doing.   I hope this answers your question.

Here's the code and sample output it generates.

```
breed [full-time-employees full-time-employee]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-full-time-employees 2  ;; 2 is enough for testing
  reset-ticks
end

to go
ask full-time-employees [
    print word "Analyzing employee number " who
    let distance-to-work 0       ;; this is a running sum
    let distance-at-work 0       ;; this is a running sum 
    let total-distance-so-far 0  ;; this will be distance-to-work + distance-at-work

    ; the loop should continue until the sum of both, distance-to-work and distance-at-work is 131 or more
    while [total-distance-so-far <= 130] [

          ; drive one more day
          let chance-distance-at-work random 50
          let chance-distance-to-work random 50

          print word "......chance-distance-to-work today = " chance-distance-to-work
          print word "......chance-distance-at-work today = " chance-distance-at-work


          ;; calculate the total distance driven so far
          set distance-to-work ( distance-to-work + chance-distance-to-work)
          set distance-at-work ( distance-at-work + chance-distance-at-work)

          set total-distance-so-far distance-to-work + distance-at-work      
          print word "...At the end of this pass of the WHILE loop, total distance so far = " total-distance-so-far
     ]

     print word "......After we exit the WHILE loop, total distance so far = " total-distance-so-far
     print word " ----------- done with employee " who
     print " "
  ]   
  tick
end
```

and sample output:

- Analyzing employee number 0 ......chance-distance-to-work today = 15
  ......chance-distance-at-work today = 39 ...At the end of this pass
  of the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 54
  ......chance-distance-to-work today = 8 ......chance-distance-at-work
  today = 37 ...At the end of this pass of the WHILE loop, total
  distance so far = 99 ......chance-distance-to-work today = 10
  ......chance-distance-at-work today = 35 ...At the end of this pass
  of the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 144 ......After we exit
  the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 144
  ----------- done with employee 0 ... Analyzing employee number 1 ......chance-distance-to-work today = 42
  ......chance-distance-at-work today = 11 ...At the end of this pass
  of the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 53
  ......chance-distance-to-work today = 23
  ......chance-distance-at-work today = 14 ...At the end of this pass
  of the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 90
  ......chance-distance-to-work today = 17
  ......chance-distance-at-work today = 31 ...At the end of this pass
  of the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 138 ......After we exit
  the WHILE loop, total distance so far = 138
  ----------- done with employee 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is the usual way to handle these questions but I found the error I was running into the entire time and I want to share it in case someone else might run into a similar problem.

So I wanted to check whether the reporter [distance-to-work + distance-at-work **<** 131] was met or not. If reporter reports false, exit the loop. Otherwise run commands and repeat. The problem was that the default value of distance-to-work and the default value of distance-at-work is 0. Hence, by default the reporter reports false and exits the loop without even running the commands once.

I first have to define the default value of the variables in such way, that the reporter reports true and hence, the commands are run. So, the revised version is below:

```
ask full-time-employees [
    set distance-to-work 100
    set distance-at-work 100

    while [distance-to-work + distance-at-work > 131] [
    let chance_distance_to_work random 100
    let chance_distance_at_work random 100

ifelse chance_distance_to_work < 3 [set distance-to-work 2 ] [
ifelse chance_distance_to_work < 8 [set distance-to-work 4 ] ... ]

ifelse chance_distance_at_work < 4  [set distance-at-work 1 ] [
ifelse chance_distance_at_work < 12 [set distance-at-work 2 ] ... ]
 ]
]
```